# Batch script: Open text file and scroll to bottom

Tags: batch-file

I've got a text file that I'd like to open using a batch script. Once it's open, I'd like to simulate pressing `CTRL + END` on the keyboard so that the cursor is placed at the very bottom of the file.

I can open the file in `Notepad` by using `start /max myFile.txt`, but I'm struggling on how to navigate to the bottom. I've read about a `SendKeys` function, but I can't seem to get this to work with sending `^{END}` to my file (I've read mixed information about whether it's available in batch scripting or not).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add `WScript.sleep 1000` prior to sending the key.

Comment: There is no native command for sending key-strokes in `cmd.exe`. You might be interested in AutoIt or AutoHotKey...?

Comment: @wOxxOm After writing `stdout` and `stderr` to a log file, it appears that `WScript` isn't a recognised command.
@aschipfl Do you recommend either of the two tools that you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is a way with [sendKeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat)

```
start /max notepad myFile.txt
call sendkeys.bat "myFile.txt" "^{END}"
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument` error at the part where `sh.SendKeys(keys)` is called. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: @helencrump - is there anything else in the error message? like the line where the problem occurs?

Comment: @helencrump - ah.It works from command line but fails if called from bat. Something need to be escaped .Will update soon.

Comment: @helencrump - sendKeys updated on github. The problem is that `^` is a metasymbol in javascript regular expressions and needed extra care (at least I think this was the reason).

Comment: It worked once, but subsequent runs of my batch script result in `Failed to find application with title myFile.txt` - do I need to wait before sending the keys, or is there something else wrong?

Comment: @helencrump  - if the file is minimized the `AppActivate` activate function wont work . BTW - are you using windows 10 , because seems the first issue is related to a windows 10 bug?

Comment: No, I'm closing the file before I run the script each time. I'm on Windows Server 2012, so no. :)

Comment: @helencrump - the second reason that `AppActivate` could fail is if the active window is already `myFile` . So for the second calls you can use `call sendkeys.bat "" "^{END}"` which will preventing changing the active window.

Comment: and `call` [doubles the caret](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133) which was the problem at first.

Comment: Great! Thanks for all of the help! :)